# How do I background correct an Illumina eset without using lumiB?

Tags: r

I'm doing some work with publicly available microarray data sets that I've downloaded from GEO. I'm having some trouble using the lumi package to process Illumina BeadArray data.

Normally when using the lumi package you would use lumiR to convert your data to a lumiBatch object, which you could then use lumiB on to background correct. lumiR requires bead standard errors in order to create a lumiBatch object, in their absence it creates an expression set. Most of lumi's functions will work on expression sets, but not lumiB. The data sets that I've downloaded only have mean intensity values and in some cases an associated P-value. Therefore I can't turn my data into lumiBatch object and thus can't background correct with lumiB.

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to background correct the expression sets. Apologies if I've phrased this unhelpfully or left out important information, I'm very new to both R and asking questions on a forum like this.

Thanks,

Emma

This is how I've been using lumiR and how I would use lumiB if it was a lumiBatch object:

```
    #Import data and convert to lumiBatch/eset object
    GSEXXX.lumi <- lumiR("GSEXXX_Raw_Data.txt",lib.mapping="lumiHumanIDMapping")

    #Using lumiB to background correct a lumiBatch object
    GSEXXX.bgcorrected <- lumiB(GSEXXX.lumi,method=c('bgAdjust','forcePositive'))
```

Comment: If no answer appears here, then asking on the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/) mailing list is appropriate; no subscription necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post my question there.